# SQLAlchemy/Flask MSSQL Query hangs indefiniteley when run under Apache

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

My app uses a couple of different DBs on the same MSSQL server (read only). My problem is that one of the two MSSQL connections always works fine, whereas the other hangs indefinetely on the first query until Flask cuts off the connection. This, however, only happens most of the time when the app is running under Apache. When I run the flask test server, everything is fine.

I've surrounded the MSSQL query with logging messages and am therefore positive that the bug is in that particular query. It is just a simple lookup by primary key, like this:

```
db.query(Record).get(id)
```

The DBs are accessed through different engines whose URIs only differ by the database name.

My problem is that I have no idea on how to start debugging this. Any tips?

[EDIT] I've managed to get SQLAlchemy logging going under Apache. I've set echo=True on the engine, and it doesn't output anything at all. It just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem doesn't have to do with Apache but with connection timeout. Whereas the MySQL engine gives an error message when trying to execute a query on an expired server connection, the MSSQL engine just silently stalls forever. Adding pool_recycle=3600 to create_engine() solved the issue.